# Inverse functions and $f(x)=x$

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Is every solution of $f(x)=x$ a solution of $f^{-1}(x) = f(x)$?

If not, why not?

Can we not do the following ?
\begin{eqnarray}
 f(x)&=&x\\
f(f(x))&=&f(x)=x\\
 f^{-1}(x)&=&f(x)\\
\end{eqnarray}

Also, what about the converse of this statement?

What if a function is invertible (bijective) only in a certain domain?

Comment: If $f$ is an invertible function, then yes... the fixed points of $f$ are also fixed points of $f^{-1}$.  This since if $f(a)=a$ you have $f^{-1}(f(a))=f^{-1}(a)$ and simplifying the LHS we have $a=f^{-1}(a)$ so $a$ being a fixed point of $f$ implies $a$ is also a fixed point of $f^{-1}$.  The reverse can be shown the same way.

Comment: $f(x)=x$ is the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element#Examples)function, the simplest type of [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)), preserving equality with its inverse (and hence also composition of itself) over its whole (nonrestricted) domain (notwithstanding application of units, since pure functions are just numerical), which is necessarily also one-to-one (bijectively invertible) over its entire Graph (domain-codomain).

Comment: The rule holds if $x$ belongs to the invertible domain. (Consider $f(x)=x^2, f^{-1}(x)=-\sqrt x$ where $x<0$.)